# Single table inheritance and has_many issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**I have a models like**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Plant < Group
  has_many :plants_sub_plants, foreign_key: 'plant_id'
  has_many :sub_plants, through: :plants_sub_plants
end

class PlantSubPlant < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plant, foreign_key: 'plant_id'
    belongs_to :sub_plant, foreign_key: 'sub_plant_id'
end

class SubPlant < Plant
     has_many :plants_sub_plants, foreign_key: 'sub_plant_id'
     has_many :plants, through: :plants_sub_plants
end
```

**Migration:**

```
class CreateTablePlantsSubPlants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :plants_sub_plants do |t|
      t.belongs_to :plant
      t.belongs_to :sub_plant
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :plants_sub_plants, :plant_id
    add_index :plants_sub_plants, :sub_plant_id
  end
end
```

**Now When i do below, it blows up.  Why is it not calling the inner join?**

```
$Plant.first.sub_plants

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'groups.plant_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups`  WHERE `groups`.`type` IN ('SubPlant') AND `groups`.`plant_id` = 16
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'groups.plant_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups`  WHERE `groups`.`type` IN ('SubPlant') AND `groups`.`plant_id` = 16
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have a `plant_id` column in your `groups` table.

Comment: Well it should not no in `groups` table.  It should go in the INNER Join table

Comment: Can you also show your schema.rb file?

Answer (score 1):

```
class SubPlant < Plant
     has_many :plants_sub_plants, foreign_key: 'sub_plant_id'
     has_many :plants, through: :plants_sub_plants
end
```

should be

`class SubPlant < ActiveRecord::Base`

```
 has_many :plants_sub_plants, foreign_key: 'sub_plant_id'
     has_many :plants, through: :plants_sub_plants
end
```

Comment: it's the concept if Single table inheritance where everything in queried from a single table but with different `type`.